# triggers and helper class to update quoteline items from account

Tags: apex, trigger, helper

```
trigger ct on Account (after insert, after update, before insert, before update) 
{    
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<id> oppIds = new Set<id>(); 

    for(Account ac : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(ac.Closed__c==true)
            accIds.add(ac.Id);
    }
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();    
    for(Opportunity opp : [select id, Closed__c from Opportunity where AccountId in: accIds])        
    {
        opp.Closed__c = True;
        opp.CloseDate= system.today()+5;
        oppsToUpdate.add(opp);        
    }   
    update oppsToUpdate;

  //  for(opportunity o: [select id, closed__c from opportunity where AccountId IN: oppIds]){
  //      if(o.Closed__c==true)
   //         oppIds.add(o.Id);
   // }

    List<Quote> qq = new List<Quote>();
    for(quote q : [select id, Closed__c from quote where OpportunityId in:oppIds])
    {
        q.Closed__c=TRUE;
        qq.add(q);
    }
    update qq;
}
```

I have to update quoteline items from account. i.e when account field is updated, it should automatically update opportunity, quote and quoteline items field.

Comment: Currently you have done for Opportunity and Quote,  So you are expecting to update same for Quote Line Item - Correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed checking for those accounts who's values recently made to false and you haven't queried the Opportunities related to those accounts. Hence, your code does not update the opportunities and quotes when you are making your account closed==false as per your requirement.

```
trigger TriggerRating on Account (after insert,after update) {

        Set<id> accIdsclosed = new Set<id>();
        Set<id> accIdsopen = new Set<id>();
        Map<id,Boolean> MapWithAccidToClosed =new Map<id,Boolean>();
        for(Account ac : Trigger.new)
        { 
            if(ac.Closed__c==true){
                MapWithAccidToClosed.put(ac.Id,true);
            }else{
                MapWithAccidToClosed.put(ac.Id,false);
            }
        }
        List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();    
        for(Opportunity opp : [select id, Closed__c,AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId in: MapWithAccidToClosed.keySet()])        
        {
            if(MapWithAccidToClosed.get(opp.AccountId)==true ){
                opp.Closed__c = True;
                oppsToUpdate.add(opp);
            }
            else if(MapWithAccidToClosed.get(opp.AccountId)==false){
                opp.Closed__c = false;
                oppsToUpdate.add(opp);
            }
        }
        update oppsToUpdate;
        List<Quote> qq = new List<Quote>();
        Map<id,Boolean> MapWithOppidToClosed =new Map<id,Boolean>();
        for(Opportunity o : oppsToUpdate)
        { 
            if(o.Closed__c==true){
                MapWithOppidToClosed.put(o.Id,true);
            }else{
                MapWithOppidToClosed.put(o.Id,false);
            }
        }

        for(quote q : [select id, Closed__c,OpportunityId from quote where OpportunityId in:MapWithOppidToClosed.keySet()])
        {
            if(MapWithOppidToClosed.get(q.OpportunityId)==true ){
                q.Closed__c = True;
                qq.add(q);
            }
            else if(MapWithOppidToClosed.get(q.OpportunityId)==false){
                q.Closed__c = false;
                qq.add(q);
            }
        }
        update qq;
    }
```

This will achieve your solution. if worked, select it as your answer.

Comment: It is advisable to put some approach or suggestion is textual format rather than posting entire codebase

Comment: @SantanuBoral Thanks for your suggestion. Will take care of this.

Comment: As-is, this answer is a "code dump" (where you only post code with no explanation). Such answers are typically low-quality and generate a lot of "that didn't work" and "try this instead" back-and-forth in the comments. High-quality answers will typically explain _what_ the problem is, _why_ it is a problem, _how_ to fix it, and _why_ the fix works. Doing so makes answers useful not just to the person who originally asked the question, but also to others that read this question with similar (but different) issues.

Comment: Actually, its updating opportunity but not to quote.

Comment: will update the answer with all mention points by @DerekF